# Delete all old entries

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I need to delete all old entries and save 20 first, but I have problem with my code:

```
DELETE FROM info WHERE account='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20,x
```

I need to replace the `x` with the last ID.

How can I get the last ID?

Comment: If id is an incremental field, i.e. the last id is always the biggest one, you could simply use a "SELECT MAX(id)..."

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to keep the 20 latest entries, with the 20 highest IDs, and delete the rest?

Comment: Have you thought this through. How often do you run this? What if there is only 18 accounts. Add one and then run it?

Comment: Yes i need the last 20 entries by account and delete if number of entries > 20 i have now `SELECT id FROM info WHERE account='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20,20
- DELETE FROM info WHERE account='".$id."' AND id<".$do['id']`its work but takes a lot of ram no ?

Comment: I would love to read the use case for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the ID you need to delete from with a `20,1` limit ordered by the last entry.

```
SELECT account FROM `info` ORDER BY account DESC LIMIT 20,1
```

So if you have 23 records the result will be 3 which is the ID you need to delete from.

```
DELETE FROM info WHERE account <= '" . $id . "'
```

***Make sure that the `account` column is properly indexed!***

Comment: Prix, you are suggesting an alternative.

Comment: @ApulGupta more like a solution this way he doesn't need to find from what ID he needs to delete from as it will automatically check the table and grab the ID he needs to delete from and if there is less than 20 records it will return nothing hence he can avoid executing the DELETE. I also believe that it would query and read only the last few ids rather than going thru the entire table?

Comment: Yes this solution work but its good for a ajax call ? I have just edit `LIMIT 20,20` for 1 query and if ID not empty execute delete

Comment: @user3649872 it needs to be `20,1` as you only need the `ID` you need to delete from. As for the AJAX it depends on how frequent you will query it and how your code uses it which I don't know.

Comment: @ApulGupta the `EXPLAIN` says that it will read only 21 entries which means it will read from the end of the table which would be optimal for his case I guess?